# Website for French antonyms

Tags: choix-de-mot, ressources

When trying to understand a word it helps me to see the word in relation to it's antonyms.

Is there a website that gives me a list of the antonyms for every French word?

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your post to be less broad... "every French word".... no dictionary has such a thing.  It may be useful to add specific details to your question about the problem you are having as well.

Comment: @PatrickSebastien : The results I got where exactly what I wanted. If you have other resources that list antonyms that you consider to be useful, feel free to post them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try :

[www.antonyme.org/](http://www.antonyme.org/)

and

[fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/antonyme](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/antonyme)

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Crisco](http://www.crisco.unicaen.fr/des/), provided by Caen University, it gives synonyms and antonyms.